# Using noHistory=true but opening previous activity when Back is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been use

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in my code so that I don't have many activities open at the same time.
The problem is the following:

Consider that I navigate navigate from **Activity A (HomePage)** to **Activity B (noHistory=true)** to **Activity C**. From Activity **C**, if I press the (hardware) back button, it takes me back to Activity **A**, not **B**. This is android:noHistory="true" , right? Is there a way to go back to Activity B and load it from scratch instead of going all the way back to Activity A?

Thanks!

Comment: the whole point of no history is so that you dont go back to that activity. using no history, the activity does not get added to the backstack.

Comment: You can start the activity B in onBackpressed() method!!!

Comment: @tj56 have got the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing @Chandrakanth's method (thanks!); I passed extras to Activity C that will tell it what activity B to open when I press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like this to go 'back' to any activity you'd like.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(startActivity.this, returnActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to get the parent activity name from there?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what you mean? The name of the activity you're leaving? For what?

Comment: Yes; so if that's for Activity C, is there a way to get the name of the class of Activity B?